# I'd like to print the same line before every line with sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I'd like to have a string inserted before 1st line and add them every other line.

Before:

```
a  
b  
c  
d
```

After:

```
INSERT  
a  
INSERT  
b  
INSERT  
c  
INSERT  
d
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good suggestion. I just did it.

Comment: I am not exactly sure why this question has been put on hold.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/.*/INSERT\n&/' file
```

or

```
sed 's/^/INSERT\n/' file
```

Output:

```
INSERT
a  
INSERT
b  
INSERT
c  
INSERT
d
```

Comment: `&` is not needed in your second solution.

Comment: @LoMaPh: Good catch! I've updated my answer.

Comment: The second solution is the nicest.

Comment: I tried in linux machine. It worked, but when I opened the output file with vim, then ^M is printed at the end of line of a, b, c and d. For example, a^M. How can I not to have ^M?

Comment: Which OS do you use? Which operating system was used to create the source file?

Comment: I just figured that it's because my source file was from dos system. So I use dos2unix command to remove ^M.

Answer (score 3):

Using [GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands):

```
$ sed 'i INSERT' file
INSERT
a
INSERT
b
INSERT
c
INSERT
d
```

Comment: **Note:** the same in POSIX is: `sed 'i\^JINSERT'`, the `^J` is created by `^V^J`

Comment: @kvantour Oh, I knew about `i\<newline>INSERT`, but not about this. Interesting!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{ print "INSERT" ORS $0 }' file
INSERT
a  
INSERT
b  
INSERT
c  
INSERT
d
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest awk would be

```
awk '{print "INSERT"}1' file
```

And after Cyrus' comment, I realize there is a much shorter version which is 2 characters shorter.

Comment: or with `gawk` and `mawk`: `awk '$0="INSERT\n" $0' file`. But I don't know why it works.

Comment: @Cyrus brilliant. It works because of the equality. `a=b` will return the value of `b` and in this case, this is not an empty string. Thus the pattern  is set to true and hence it will print `$0`.   You have to remember that awk lines look like `(pattern){rule}` with default rule `print $0`

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do `$0="INSERT\n" $0` you're telling awk to do string concatenation on $0 and then re-split $0 into fields - that'll be noticeably slower than simply printing INSERT then $0 for files large enough that efficiency matters.